# Does anybody share me the code to implement the Azure single sign on by using clientid, redirect uri, tenant I'd without showing any login popup?

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

Does anybody share me the code of Azure single sign on by using clientid, redirect uri, tenant I'd to implement that in my asp net windows application without showing any login popup to user and that automatically get the users current login authentication?

Azure single sign on without showing popup

***startup.cs***

```cs
PublicClientApplicationBuilder builder= PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithAuthority(authorityUrl).WithRedirectUri(redirectUrl);
IPublicClientApplication app = builder.Build();
AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes) .ExecuteAsync(); 
string accessToken = result.AccessToken;
```

Comment: Share your effort if you tried something and got stuck with any errors/blockers.

Comment: What is the framework you are using ?Please share your `configuration` and `Program.cs` file.

Comment: PublicClientApplicationBuilder builder= PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithAuthority(authorityUrl).WithRedirectUri(redirectUrl); IPublicClientApplication app = builder.Build();AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes) .ExecuteAsync(); string accessToken = result.AccessToken; this approach showing me one popup for few secs till getting my current login. Its working fine in my local but when i deploy it to the server that popup throwing error. Also i tried the confidential client approach. But that access token dont have any user data. framework 4.7

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to Implement `SSO` without showing the login popup.

In Visual Studio create a new Web Application with .NET 4.7 Framework and select `None` in Authentication.

[image]

Add new class file with name `startup.cs`.

- In `Azure Active Directory` create the `new App Registration`.

[image]

[image]

- In the newly created App Registrations => Overview pane, you can find the details of `client` and `TenantID`.

[image]

***My `Web.config` file:***

```cs
 <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientId" value="****" />
    <add key="Tenant" value="****" />
    <add key="Authority" value="https://login.DomainName.com/{0}/v2.0" />
    <add key="redirectUri" value="https://localhost:PortNo/" />
  </appSettings>
```

> But that access token dont have any user data. framework 4.7

- Check whether you have provided the correct Authority URL.

Make sure you have given the `Redirect URI` Correctly.
We need to provide both `local` as well as `Deployed Application URL`.

[image]

Refer the [GitHub](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-iwa-v2) which uses `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuthAsync`, which authenticates the user with Windows Credentials.